# Computer management tool does not refresh the Message Queueing, private queues

Tags: windows-10, command-line, configuration-managment, queue-management

I'm working on a Windows-10 computer, version 2004 (OS Build 19041.1052).

I'm working with some new Message Queueing items, which can be seen in "Computer Management" tool, "Services and Applications", "Message Queuing":

```
 - Outgoing Queues
 - Private Queues
   - ...
   - own_receive
   - own_send
 - System Queues
```

I'm working on some applications, who are adding and retrieving messages from those queues.

I cannot use <kbd>F5</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd>, or use the <kbd>Refresh</kbd> button, none of them works (the values in the "Number of Messages" column stay the same even if messages have been added or deleted from the queues).
In order to refresh the views on those queues (in order to know if a message has been added or deleted from a queue), I always need to stop and restart the entire "Computer Management" tool and surf to "Services and Applications", "Message Queuing", ..., every time again.

Is this a known issue and in case yes, is there a patch (foreseen) for this?

**Edit**
In case you know any commandline tool for getting this information, this might also solve the issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to right-click "Private Queues" and then click Refresh.

If this option has disappeared, you could use an alternate viewer:

- [Mqueue viewver](https://www.mqueue.net/)
- [MSMQ QXplorer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/msmqqxplorer/files/)
  (old software but may still work)

Comment: The option did not disappear, I was just so surprised seeing the present `Refresh` button appearing not to work, that I forgot to look further. :-)